# extract json data in php and print it

Tags: php, json

```
array(2) { 
    ["data"]=> array(1) 
    { 
        ["MemberData"]=> array(1) 
        { 
            ["Verified"]=> string(1) "Y" 
        } 
    } 
    ["error"]=> array(2) 
    { 
        ["code"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["text"]=> string(0) "" 
    } 
}
```

/i want to print verified value in a php page/

Comment: no attempts whatsoever?

Comment: echo $array['data']['MemberData']['Verified']; ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to do it from PHP to javascript:

```
var ar = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($array) ?>' );
//ar[1]['MemberData'];  //first memberdata value

console.log(ar[1]['MemberData'].value);
```

and from javascript to php you need to use ajax

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
     url: 'xxxxxxx',
    dataType: 'json', 
    data: {array:array, //here you can pass the verified value of the array or the whole array if you want 
        },
    success: function(data) {
            if(data.success == true){ 

            }
            },
    error: function(data) {
            if(data.success != true){ 

            }
            },
        });
```

And then you can read it like normal POST on PHP-side.

Otherway of doing it would be to reload the URL with ?verified='javascript_array_value' and read it with GET

Comment: thanxxxx...but i want to do it only in php ..